# Express application with two API(routes) that have two responses 1)error 2) success

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

This is the question regarding REST api using express.
Complete the Express application that runs on port 3000 and connects to a Database assignment. 
The database should have a user collection which contains the following user details.

a) userId - "user1",
  firstName - "Akshay",
  lastName - "Kumar",
  email - "khiladi@gmail.com"

b) userId - "user2"
    firstName - "Rajnikanth",
    lastName - "",
    email - "boss@rajnikanth.com"

**THE ABOVE DATABASE PART IS NOT NECCESARY**(I posted the whole question just in case)

The application should have the following api - 
  /users - returns the JSON of all users in the DB
  /users/:userId - returns the object of a single user based on the userId passed

Edit the following files in the given application - 
response.js
app.js

And make this a fully functional REST API with following two kind of responses - 
a) Error response - 
  {‘isError’:true,'status’: 500,'errorMessage':’Some error message’,successMessage:null}
b) Success response - 
{‘isError’:false,'status’: 200,'errorMessage':null,successMessage:’Some result’}

NOTE: You are not required to use app.listen(). This will be handled by the system.

*/

I have tried this solution :

```
   app.get('/users', function(req, res, err) {

    UserModel.find(function(err, result){
         if(err) {
            let apiResponse = response.generateResponse(true, 500, "Some 
     error message", null);
            res.send(apiResponse);
        } else {
            let apiResponse = response.generateResponse(false, 200, "Some 
    result", result);
            res.send(apiResponse);
        }

      });
  });

  app.get('/users/:userId', function(req, res, err){

     BlogModel.findOne({ 'blogId': req.params.userId }, (err, result) => {

        if (err) {
            let apiResponse = response.generateResponse(true, 500, "Some error message", null);
            res.send(apiResponse);

        }  else {
            let apiResponse = response.generateResponse(false, 200, "Some result", result);
            res.send(apiResponse);
        }
    });
});
```

But it gives some logical error message.
I have to submit the code online where i answer my assignment and their website compiler just tell if there is a sytnax error or a logical error.

As i mentioned earlier i have to submit it on website so cant really get results but this code works fine when i run it on my visual studio code.
I think there is some logical error which i am not able to figure out.

ALL THE .JS FILES:

### **app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const UserModel = require('./User.js');

let db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://testuser:password123@ds149252.mlab.com:49252/assignment', { useMongoClient: true });
const responseLib = require('./responseLib');

app.get('/users', function(req, res, err) {

    UserModel.find(function(err, result){
         if(err) {
            let apiResponse = response.generateResponse(true, 500, "Some error message", null);
            res.send(apiResponse);
        } else {
            let apiResponse = response.generateResponse(false, 200, "Some result", result);
            res.send(apiResponse);
        }

    });
});

app.get('/users/:userId', function(req, res, err){

     BlogModel.findOne({ 'blogId': req.params.userId }, (err, result) => {

        if (err) {
            let apiResponse = response.generateResponse(true, 500, "Some error message", null);
            res.send(apiResponse);

        }  else {
            let apiResponse = response.generateResponse(false, 200, "Some result", result);
            res.send(apiResponse);
        }
    });
});



module.exports = app;
```

### **Users.js**

```
// importing mongoose module
// importing mongoose module
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
// import schema 
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let userSchema = new Schema(
    {
        userId: {
            type: String,
            unique: true
        },
        firstName: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        },
        lastName: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        }
    }
)

mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

### **responseLib.js**

```
let generateResponse = (isError,status,errorMessage,successMessage) =>{

let response = {

    isError : isError,
    status : status,
    errorMessage : errorMessage,
    successMessage : successMessage
}
return response

};// end generate response. 

module.exports = {generateResponse:generateResponse}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your `/users/:userId` routes code, it should be `UserModel.findOne()`. Also there is no point in declaring `err` in your app.get routes function since you're already declaring it in the callback function later on as `(err, result)`

```
  app.get('/users', (req, res) => {

    UserModel.find((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else if (result == undefined || result == null || result == '') {
            res.send("No User Data Found");
        } else {
            res.send(result);
        }
    });
 });

 app.get('/users/:userId', (req, res) => {
    UserModel.findOne({ 'userId': req.params.userId }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else if (result == undefined || result == null || result == '') {
            res.send("No Such User Found");
        } else {
            res.send(result);
        }
    });
 });`
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit hard to tell exactly the problem, without knowing what is the "logical error". But my guess is that you are not setting the Status in the HTTP response. In a HTTP response, you have Headers and Body, your generated response is the body. But you do not set the Status in the Headers.

So you must do `res.status(200)` or `res.status(500)` in order to set the status in the header. You should do this, before the `res.send`, because `res.send` is the action that returns the response. While `res.status` you are preparing your response before sending.

You can check the [documentation here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.status).

Comment: So i add res.status after res.send ?? about the logical error i just want to know if it fits the logic of question or not.(am i doing what is asked or not?).  Thank You

Comment: No, you should do before. Res.send will send your response, so if you do after, it will have no effect. By your description, I think that with the Status Header, it will be correct. It looks like you are in the correct direction.

Comment: So i tried adding res.status but it says logic is not correct and gave me some hint. 
HINT: Take the data as parameters and return the object from the library function.

Answer (score -1):

**direct copy-paste for assignment. It is a working code.**

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const UserModel = require('./User.js');

let db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://testuser:password123@ds149252.mlab.com:49252/assignment', { useMongoClient: true });
const response = require('./responseLib');
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {

    UserModel.find((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            let apiResponse = response.generateResponse(true, 500, "Some error message", null);
            res.send(apiResponse);
        } else if (result ===undefined || result ===null || result ==='') {
            let apiResponse = response.generateResponse(true, 500, "Some error message", null);
            res.send(apiResponse);
        } else {
             let apiResponse = response.generateResponse(false, 200, null, 'Some result');
            res.send(apiResponse);
        }
    });
 });

 app.get('/users/:userId', (req, res) => {
    UserModel.findOne({ 'userId': req.params.userId }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            let apiResponse = response.generateResponse(true, 500, "Some error message", null);
            res.send(apiResponse);
        } else if (result ===undefined || result ===null || result ==='') {
           let apiResponse = response.generateResponse(true, 500, "Some error message", null);
            res.send(apiResponse);
        } else {
             let apiResponse = response.generateResponse(false, 200, null, 'Some result');
            res.send(apiResponse);
        }
    });
 });



module.exports = app;
```

**responseLib.js**

```
let generateResponse = (isError,status,errorMessage,successMessage) =>{
   let response = {

    isError : isError,
    status : status,
    errorMessage : errorMessage,
    successMessage : successMessage
};
return response; 


};// end generate response. 

module.exports = {generateResponse:generateResponse};
```

**user.js**

```
// importing mongoose module
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// import schema 
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let userSchema = new Schema(
    {
        userId: {
            type: String,
            unique: true
        },
        firstName: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        },
        lastName: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        }
    }
);
mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

**direct copy-paste for assignment. It is a working code.**